# Weighted metric (or semi-metric) with incorporated distance between Dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Im trying to construct a distance Measure between two vectors, that takes into account also the distance between the Dimensions. I will illustrate my Problem with some examples:

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $d(x,y)$ fullfills the metric-axioms (but im not shure if the triangle-equality must hold - so a semi-metric could also probably do the job).

1.)

$x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=1,x_4=1$;

$y_1=0,9;y_2=1,1;y_3=1;y_4=1$;

$d(x,y)=0,1 $

In this example 0.1 is moved from $_1$ to $_2$, so the distance between the coordinates is 1, times 0.1 gives $d(x,y)=0.1$.

2.)
$x_1=1;x_2=1;x_3=1;x_4=1$;

$y_1=0,9;y_2=1;y_3=1;y_4=1,1$;

$d(x,y)=0.3$

In the second case 0.1 is moved from $x_1$ to $_4$, so the distance between the coordinates is 3 times 0.1 gives $d(x,y)=0.3$.

3.)

$x_1=2;x_2=2;x_3=2;x_4=2$;

$y_1=1,9;y_2=2,1;y_3=1.9;y_4=2,1;$

$d(x,y)=0.2$

In this example 0.1 is moved from 1 to 1 equates to 0.1. Also 0.1 is moved from $_3$ to $_4$. In total we moved 0.2 mass from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$. Equates to $d(x,y)=0.2$

4.)

$x_1=2;x_2=2;x_3=2;x_4=2$;

$y_1=1,9;y_2=1,8;y_3=2,2;y_4=2,1$;

$d(x,y)=0.5$

In this case either 0.1 is moved from $_1$ to $_4$ and 0.2 from $_2$ to $_3$. Equates to $d(x,y)=0.3+0.2$. Some more explanations are also possible,i.e: 0.1 is moved from $x_1$ to $y_3$ equals to $d_1(x,y)=0.2$. 0.1 are moved from $x_2$ to $y_3$, $d_2(x,y)=0.1$. 0.1 is moved from $x_2$ to $y_4$, $d_3(x,y)=0.2$. $d(x,y)=d_1+d_2+d_3=0.5.

Im trying to define $d(x,y)$ very general.
My first guess was to somehow combine the euclidean distance $\sqrt{(x_i-y_j)^2}$ and the euclidean distance $\sqrt{(i-j)^2}$ but it didnt worked out to well :) I would appreciate any help!

Comment: what is your exact thinking in assigning these particular distance values? how is dimension involved? I don't yet see it; the number of differing coordinates?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the number of differing coordinates

Comment: The number of differing coordinates is called the Hamming distance $d_H$. You seem to be wanting a combo of the $\ell^1$ norm distance and $d_H$?

Comment: Why the difference between case 1 and 2: both have $d_H$ equal to $2$ and $d_1$ distance equal to $0.2$ but still they get different values assigned by you?

Comment: Well in the first case we moved 0.1 from $x_1$ to $y_2$, so the distance between the coordinates is 1. In the second case we moved 0.1 from $x_1$ to $y_4$, so the distance between the coordinates is 3.

Comment: Why the large difference in value between 3 and 4: they both differ in all coordinates (only 0.1 max in 3, but 0.2 max in 4) and still the values are quite different. Is there a rationale there too?

Comment: Well in 3.) we moved 0.1 from $x_1$ to $y_1$ equates to 0.1. We also moved 0.1 from we moved 0.1 from $x_3$ to $y_4$. In total we moved 0.2 mass for one step. In case 4.) we moved either 0.1 from $x_1$ to $y_4$ and 0.2 from $x_2$ to $y_3$. Equates to 0.3+0.2. A second explanation is also possible, but thats the rationale.